# How to create Casbin model and policy for roles and resources that belongs to folders?

Tags: acl, rbac, casbin

I'm trying to create a [Casbin](https://casbin.org/) RBAC + ACL model. The business requirement is as follows:

We have an Organization, and within Organization you can create Folders. There are special folders like Workspace folder. Basically, the folders are a way to limit access to certain resources, resources that you "put" in those folders. If you have acess to a folder, you immediately have access to all of its children, unless explicitly overridden by the folder owner. Example:

[image]

Now, we also have features and permissions. A role is a set of permissions. Features examples: users, computers, scripts. Permissions examples: edit user, delete user, publish script.

So now, I'm trying to bring this all together to come up with the correct Casbin model. ***From my understanding***, I need to define roles and their permissions, folders hierarchy, which users have access to each folder, which roles a user has, and which resources are inside a folder. In that way, when a request comes asking if the user "John" can publish script "Untitled", the model would look in which folder "Untitled" is, and then see whether "John" has the permission to that folder and also has the permission to publish scripts (if "John" has "bot developer" role).

**Roles and their permissions**

```
p, role:workspaceAdmin, feature:user, edit
p, role:workspaceAdmin, feature:user, delete
p, role:workspaceAdmin, feature:workspace, edit
p, role:botDeveloper, feature:script, publish
```

So, the workspace admin role can edit or delete users, can edit the workspace. The bot developer role can publish script.

**Folders hierarchy**

```
g2, folder:watson, script:untitled

g2, folder:xpto, folder:doc
g2, folder:xpto, folder:infra
g2, folder:xpto, folder:watson

g2, folder:watson, folder:projectX
g2, folder:watson, folder:projectY
g2, folder:infra, folder:project66
g2, folder:doc, folder:marcela
```

**Which users have access to each folder**

```
g, user:joba, folder:watson
```

**Which roles a user has**

```
g, user:joba, role:botDeveloper
```

**Which resources are inside a folder**

```
g2, folder:watson, script:untitled
```

With that in place, the following request returns **false**, where I expected to be **true**: `user:joba, script:untitled, publish`. Because user "joba" has permission to "publish" "feature" "script", has access to folder "watson", and "script" named "untitled" belongs to that folder.

---

**Model**

```
[request_definition]
r = sub, obj, action

[policy_definition]
p = sub, obj, action

[role_definition]
g = _, _
g2 = _, _

[policy_effect]
e = some(where (p.eft == allow)) && !some(where (p.eft == deny))

[matchers]
m = g(r.sub, p.sub) && g2(r.obj, p.obj) && r.act == p.act
```

**Policy**

```
p, role:workspaceAdmin, feature:user, edit
p, role:workspaceAdmin, feature:user, delete
p, role:workspaceAdmin, feature:workspace, edit
p, role:botDeveloper, feature:script, publish

g2, folder:watson, script:untitled

g2, folder:xpto, folder:doc
g2, folder:xpto, folder:infra
g2, folder:xpto, folder:watson

g2, folder:watson, folder:projectX
g2, folder:watson, folder:projectY
g2, folder:infra, folder:project66
g2, folder:doc, folder:marcela

g, user:joba, folder:watson
g2, folder:watson, script:untitled
```

**Request**

```
user:joba, script:untitled, publish
```

Comment: I don't think you trully understand Casbin RBAC well, plz read the docs again: https://casbin.org/docs/en/rbac

Answer (score 1):

you didn't describe relationship between `user` & `role`, `script` & `feature`

```
g, user:joba, role:botDeveloper
g2, folder:watson, script:untitled

g2, script:untitled, feature:script
```

And the model file `action` should be `act` or change `r.act` and `p.act` into `r.action` and `p.action`

I recommand you to read [docs](https://casbin.org/docs/en/rbac), thanks

Comment: My mistake about “act”. I’ve read the docs. You explicitly defined “script:untitled” there as feature , but I want to avoid that. “Script” is a feature, but “script:untitled” or “script:name_of_script” is the resource. I can have thousands of resources. I’d like to only specify the roles to feature permissions, and implicitly apply the rules on resources of that feature

Comment: It's easy to solve if using wildcard in policy file, plz refer to https://github.com/casbin/casbin/blob/master/examples/rbac_with_pattern_policy.csv